# Why is spectral density only defined for stationary processes?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, fourier-transform, spectral-analysis

I read Brockwell and Davis(2016), Shumway and Stoffer(2016), and Stoica and Moses(2004). However, none of them laid out clearly the reasoning behind the presumption of stationarity when conducting spectral analysis on a time series.

I understand we typically need to detrend the time series as necessary data pre-processing for spectral analysis, because otherwise the first cosine coefficient could distort the estimates/periodogram.(frequency close to zero could have very large spectrum).

But simple detrending doesn't make the process stationary. It may well have periodicity/seasonality built in, although it may not have a unit root (unit root stationarity tests are rendered useless in this case).

Based on above, how could we carry out a spectral analysis on a periodic time series which is not stationary when spectral analysis is only defined for stationary processes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote [Brockwell and Davis](https://books.google.com/books/about/Introduction_to_Time_Series_and_Forecast.html?id=P3fhDAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button#v=onepage&q&f=false):
"[t]he summability of $|\gamma(\cdot)|$ implies that the series converges absolutely..."

When you look at the definition of the spectral density
$$
f(\lambda) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \sum_{h=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ih\lambda} \gamma(h), \hspace{10mm} - \infty < \lambda < \infty,
$$
the sum would be undefined if $\gamma(\cdot)$ was the autocovariance function of  a periodic process. Intuitively periodic processes' autocovariance functions don't "die out."

Comment: thanks very much for pointing it out; could you also take a look at my question in last paragraph? Shumway and Stoffer are actually using periodic process in an example to illustrate the idea of periodogram.

Comment: @stucash that isn’t an infinite sum, so there’s no risk of undefinedness. Also, it’s jusy like [running a regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/249198/from-a-statistical-perspective-fourier-transform-vs-regression-with-fourier-bas/254981#254981) if you prefer to think of it like that.

Comment: thanks a lot that’s exactly what I missed in my head, although it’s actually very obvious!